# Improve computation time of numerous binomial processes in hierachical model (openbugs/winbugs)

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, convergence, openbugs, binomial-cdf

I am currently developing a hierarchical bayesian model in Openbugs that involves a lot (about 6000 sites) of binomial processes. It describes successive removal electric fishing events/pass and the general structure is as follow:

```
N_tot[i]<-d[i] * S[i]
d[i]~dgamma(0.01,0.01)

for (i in 1:n_sites){
    for (j in 1:n_pass[i]){
        logit(p[i,j])~dnorm(0,0.001)
        N[i,j] <- N_tot[i] - sum( C[i,1:(j-1)] )
        C[i,j] ~ dbin( p[i,j] , N[i,j] )
    }
}
```

where n_sites is the total number of sites i'm looking at. n_pass[i] is the number of fishing pass carried out in site i. N[i,j] is the number of fish in site i when doing fish pass j. N_tot[i] is the total number of fish in site i before any fish pass and it is the product of the density at the site d[i] times the surface of the site S[i] (the surface is known). C[i,j] is the number of fish caught in site i during fish pass j. p[i,j] is the probability of capture in site i for fish pass j.

Each sites as on average 3 fishing pass which is a lot of successive binomial process which typically takes a lot of time to compute/converge.
I can't approximate the binomial process because the catches are typically small.

So I'm a bit stuck and i'm looking for suggestions/alternatives to deal with this issue.

Thanks in advance

edit history:
15-11-2016: added prior definitions for d and p following on @M_Fidino request for clarification

Comment: Can you calculate `N` outside of the model instead of within?

Comment: the whole point of the model is  trying to estimate N and factors affecting the probability of capture

Comment: Then which of these are data included within the model and which are parameters you wish you to estimate? Without including additional information its really difficult to make any suggestions.

Comment: @M_Fidino


C[i,j] is the catch data

unknowns to estimate = N_tot[i] , p[i,j] ,N[i,j]
where N_tot[i] = d[i] * S[i] 

the total abundance is equal to the density  times the surface S[i] 

priors:

logit(p[i,j]) ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
d[i] ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001) 
 
The actual model is a bit more complex with multiple hierachical levels on the density and the probability of capturebut even w/o that it is still slow to converge

I'm interested in knowing if other people using BUGS run into these issues and how they deal with it.

Comment: This will likely only offer VERY small gains but you could remove `N` from the model  `C[i,j] ~ dbin( p[i,j] , (N_tot[i] - sum( C[i,1:(j-1)] )))`. That should be a little more efficient.  Furthermore, as you are supplying `C` as data you could do some of the summations outside of the model instead of within. That way you are not using `sum` a whole bunch of times.